# Retrive wordpress Contact form 7 data instantly after submission

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, contact-form-7, contact-form, wordpress-gutenberg

i am using contact form 7 as a form builder. The requirement is when a user submit his form, after clicking the submit button there should open a new window that will display all his data that he has submitted. is there any solution for this?

I want the user submitted data in new tab so that he can veiw his submitted details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Contact Form 7 custom DOM [events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/) to get the submitted data and output it on a new window.

Try out this javascript code . Tested and working.

```
document.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function (event) {
    var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
    var output_html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        output_html += inputs[i].name + ' : ' + inputs[i].value + '</br>';
    }
    var newWindow = window.open();
    newWindow.document.write(output_html);

}, false);
```

Or add this in your theme's function.php

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'ze_cf7_data_in_new_tab');
function ze_cf7_data_in_new_tab(){
    ?>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function(event) {
                var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
                var output_html = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    output_html += inputs[i].name + ' : ' + inputs[i].value + '</br>';
                }
                var newWindow = window.open();
                newWindow.document.write(output_html);

            }, false);
        </script>

    <?php
    }
```

Comment: can you please further assist me with how to use this code, where should I put it? kindly explain a little more in detail. Thank you!

Comment: you can use this code in your theme's footer.php file within `<script></script>` tag  Or in your theme's javascript file where you are writing your javascript code.

Or i can edit the code so you have to put the code only in your theme's function.php.

`wpcf7submit`  is contact form 7 dom event that Fires when an Ajax form submission has completed successfully then we are calling that event and getting the submitted data and storing the data results in a html string.

Comment: thank you so much for your gentle response.I have tried adding function.php code. It works perfectly fine for me. Much appreciated.